# Try to compare different types in old fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm using `gfortran 7 (Ubuntu)` to compile an old fortran code.

I'm facing the follow error:

```
MYOLDCODE.f90:864:13:

         if  (star (i) .eq. ' '   .and.&
             1
Error: Operands of comparison operator â.eq.â at (1) are REAL(4)/CHARACTER(1)
```

I think I'm trying to compare a real number to a blank space char. I don't know why the original coder do this. He dead in 90's so I can only ask him when I go to same place he is now, but then it will be too late. Here are the code:

```
DO I = 1,KJ

    ( some code )

    WRITE(impre,7100,IOSTAT=IERRO) I,STAR(I),A2(I),B2(I),A3(I),AMPL(I),&
        &CIA(I),SITU(I),A4(I),A5(I),CIF(I)
    if  (star (i) .eq. ' '   .and.& 
        &    ampl (i) .ne. 1.E20 .and.& 
        &    ampl (i) .ge. 0.5   .and.& 
        &    situ (i) .ne. 1.E20 )  then
            write (15,7777) a2(i), b2(i), a3(i), ampl(i), situ(i)
    end if
    7777    format (a3,a4,f11.7,f8.2,f8.2)
end do
7100 FORMAT (t25,I3,2X,A1,A3,A4,2X,F11.7,6(2X,F8.2) )
```

How can I compare `star (i) .eq. ' '` ?

I know nothing about fortran so please ask if you need more code/information

Comment: You cannot. Or if you want, you need to know why and what should be the result of comparing `3.1415926535` with `'  '`. That is quite peculiar. If it were an integer, I would have some idea why one might want to do that, but not with a real. I think we need more code. At least where `STAR()` is declared and assigned some value. Check that  `implicit none` is being used.

Comment: My guess (and it purely is a guess) is implicit none is not being used and the programmer has forgot to declare star as a character. But it could be any number of other things as well

Comment: The simple initial fix for this situation arising in programs written over 40 years ago is to declare the arrays in which characters are stored as CHARACTER(n) where n is sufficient for the largest substring.  That's usually CHARACTER(8) in place of DOUBLE PRECISION or CHARACTER(4) for INTEGER or default REAL.  Once it's working, you can pursue more stylish versions.

Comment: It is possibly Fortran 66 code which didn't have a character type.  In those days, characters were stored in integers or floats.  Floats were often chosen because they could store more characters than integers.  It is being printed as A1 so it must have been used to store characters.

Comment: Thanks for all you guys! Looking closer to the code I've found this: `DATA BRANCO/1H /` and then `IF(AMPL(I)-RO)31,31,9032` and `9032 STAR(I)=BRANCO` so my instinct tells me to change the "wrong" code to `if  (star (i) .eq. BRANCO ... `. Then I could compile the code. I hope I'm not doing any mess...

Comment: my first thought was "BRANCO" is some special value not expected if all goes fine, so the original (dead) coder for some reason forgot to compare it and use the blank (branco in portuguese) char.